# Issue where soft-credits will not save

Tags: javascript, soft-credit

We've been having this issue over at least one major upgrade where certain types of soft-credits just will not save, without leaving any type record in the error logs. Crediting an individual from another individual or organization works, but crediting an org or a household from an individual prevents the contribution from saving at all... if the soft-credit is removed the record will save fine. I took a video of what I mean and put it on YouTube here >> [Video of soft-credit not saving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQwfgsQ3t7o&feature=youtu.be)

I have recently installed the Automatic Soft-credit extension [Auto Soft-Credit Extension](https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.module.automaticsoftcredit) and it seems to bypass the issue, but there are many cases where I need to edit a contribution and cannot without deleting the soft-credit. Since we can't track payments toward an org or total household giving without soft-credits this leaves us with a serious issue.

Any ideas would be a great help. I am not a coder, but willing to use phpMyAdmin to look at the database or look into php code issues.

Thanks. We are on CiviCRM 4.6.22 and the latest Drupal 7 on a Debian 8 server with Apache.

Comment: I am experiencing this same problem. When I take your second suggested approach of looking at Network>HTTP POST>Reponses, I see 4 lines, the 3rd begin status=success. I'm not clear on what to do with this information. Is there something in particular to look for? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great to hear you're using my extension!

Since the extension works but the form doesn't, that strongly suggests the problem is with this form and not the database.  From your video, it looks like a JavaScript issue.  Here's what I would look at:

Press F12 in your web browser to bring up the dev tools.

- Look at the "Console" tab. Are there errors that appear there on save when the save fails vs. succeeds?  If so, check out this post: [Troubleshooting JavaScript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).  Also feel free to update your question with said errors.
- Also check the "Network tab".  Find the HTTP POST request that appears when you press "Save".  Particularly, look at the "Response" subtab (I use Firefox, terminology may be a bit different with Chrome/Edge but it's all there).  There is likely a helpful clue there.